# Remove all the odd numbers in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I already wrote code to remove all the odd numbers in an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Odd {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 6, 7));
        System.out.println(odd(mylist));
    }

    public static int odd(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) { throw new Error(); }
        int a = list.get(0);
        List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int si : list) {
            if (si % 2 != 0) { toRemove.add(si); }
        }

        list.removeAll(toRemove);
        return a;
    }
}
```

But somehow the result is always 1.Can someone point out what is my mistake?Thank you in advance

Comment: You return a single `int` from the list to display. Why does the method return an `int`?

Comment: What is the result supposed to be? Currently you're just returning the first item in the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

(1) You need to `return` the `list` object (contains Integers) after the removal of odd numbers

(2) In order to `return` the `list`, you need to change the method signature from `int` to `List<Integer>` (as return type):

You can refer the below code with comments:

```
//change the method signature to return List<Integer>
public static List<Integer> odd(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) { throw new Error(); }
        List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int si : list) {
            if (si % 2 != 0) { toRemove.add(si); }
        }

        list.removeAll(toRemove);
        return list;//return list, not int
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
int a=list.get(0);
```

You are reading only the first element of the list, which is 1, and not iterating through it.

Use either an iterator (`for each`, for example) or a regular `for` loop (using the item count from `list`).

Comment: The program does iterate the list. It removes the required items from the list. The only issue is that there is no connection between that and the result that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, the problem is that you're returning this:

```
int a = list.get(0);
```

Thus, you'll *always* get the first item in the list, regardless of what you do to it after you retrieve it.

Getting rid of `a` completely and just returning `list` will fix that issue.